# Large amount of time publishing to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, performance, time, publishing

Publishing <5Mb tile packages to ArcGIS Online is taking more than 20 minutes.  ESRI tech support has consistently given extremely vague answers that never solve and always reference server load.  <5Mb does not seems like much of a server load.

Anyone else having this same problem?

Comment: Can you please outline your workflow?

Comment: Should take 2 minutes max

Comment: Are you uploading a tpk and then publishing a tiled service from the uploaded tpk or are you publishing from ArcMap?

Comment: Smells like a potential network problem at your end? Have a try from your home computer (or another network) to pinpoint where to look next.  Perhaps something like a virus scanner is scanning any uploads?